# Rails adapter 'mysql' works on ruby irb, gives error with rake db:seed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I get the following error when running `rake db:seed` (it also gives error with migrate)

```
rake aborted!

NULL pointer given
```

I am using Rails 3.2.6 and MySQL 2.8.1.

Comment: Did you specify the database when you created your app ?
Example : 
`rails new test -d mysql`

Comment: yes, got it, thanks Rubie_Newbie